# Access to your IBM Cloud account was denied

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-cloud-infrastructure, ibm-cloud-tools, ibm-cloud-storage

I created IBM cloud object storage and a bucket. When I try to list the buckets in the storage it works but when trying to read or write from bucket I am getting access denied.

```
Ravithejs-MacBook-Pro:~$ ibmcloud cos put-object --bucket hog-cli-bucket-name --key firstOne --body /Downloads/apikey.json
FAILED
Access to your IBM Cloud account was denied. Log in again by typing ibmcloud login --sso.
```

I tried logging in with apikey and sso but running into same issue again

Answer (score 1):

Try just apikey

`ibmcloud login --apikey <replace with your api key>`

Comment: I tried that.. still same issue when accessing cos bucket

Answer (score 0):

Check the permissions for your username.

```
  ibmcloud iam user-policies <user-name>
```

You should have `Manager` permission. You can check the bucket permissions as listed in the documentation in [this link](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/services/cloud-object-storage?topic=cloud-object-storage-iam-bucket-permissions)